# MouseEnter and MouseLeave makes buttons disappear when they shouldn't be hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

If I had any hair left, I would have pulled it out by now.  I'm getting better with WPF but I'm still running into odd issues like this one.

EDIT: It has to do with the transparent background between objects in the custom control.  On a whim, I set the background on the top stackpanel to black and the control now works; I can move the mouse freely around without losing the buttons. However, I'd really like to have the transparent background in the control...

I've got a usercontrol that consists of 4 buttons, a textblock, and a stand alone image.  This is my XAML for the control:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Transparent" MouseEnter="StackPanel_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="StackPanel_MouseLeave">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        
            <Button Name="btnAdd" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Previous" Click="btnAdd_Click" 
                    BorderBrush="Transparent" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Source="/Images/add.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="imgAdd" Width="25" Height="25"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Background="Transparent" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25">Add</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>

            <Button Name="btnEdit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Previous"
                    Click="btnAdd_Click" BorderBrush="Transparent"  >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Source="/Images/edit.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="imgEdit" Width="25" Height="25"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Background="Transparent" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25">Edit</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
    
        </StackPanel>


        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" >

            <Button Name="btnPrevious" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Previous" Click="btnPrevious_Click" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Source="/Images/Previous25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="imgPrevious" Width="25" Height="25"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        
                <TextBlock Name="tblkUserType" Background="Transparent" Foreground="AntiqueWhite"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" >Usertype</TextBlock>
        
            <Button Name="btnNext" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Previous" Click="btnNext_Click" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Source="/Images/Next25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="imgNext" Width="25" Height="25"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>

        </StackPanel>

    <Image Source="/Images/Logo50px.png" Height="50" Width="50" ></Image>

</StackPanel>
</Border>
```

I added in the border to test this out further, previously I had the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events on the top .

The code behind the MouseEnter and MouseLeave are as follows:

```
    private void StackPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        btnNext.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btnPrevious.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btnAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btnEdit.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //Debug.WriteLine("mouseEnter");
    }

    private void StackPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        btnNext.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnPrevious.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnEdit.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        //Debug.WriteLine("mouseLeave");
    }
```

What is supposed to happen when I hover over the control I want the buttons to pop up / appear.

What happens is that the 4 buttons do appear when I hover over the custom control and when I navigate to the "btnNext" or "btnPrevious" the control stays "open".

If I move my cursor up to "btnAdd" or "btnEdit" about half the way up the buttons disappear because the MouseLeave event is fired.  However, all of these objects are under the same stackpanel which contains the MouseEnter and MouseLeave.

I can get to the buttons if I go to btnNext or btnPrevious then move the mouse diagonal to either btnAdd or btnEdit.  But I can't go from the tblkUserType straight up.

I was trying to fix an original issue where 1/2 way to the upper buttons and the buttons would flicker on / off.  That was "fixed" when I added in height="25" here:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25" >
```

But then I could at least continue up and make it to the buttons but it was painful to watch with all the flickering.

I don't know why this is happening or what to even search on to find anyone with the same issue...

I need to be able to get to the btnAdd and btnEdit from the tblkUserType.  I guess I'm assuming incorrectly that everything within the StackPanel (or border) would operate with the MouseEnter and MouseLeave within that coverage but I'm not understanding something.

Comment: Not an answer, but having a short look into your XAML I suggest that you, in general, should inform about a few things. A few of the same controls, e.g., have the same background, Height, etc (use Styles). Makes your markup readable and easier to change the look at one place. Furthermore use a ViewModel in code behind and Bindings in the XAML, e.g. to control the Visibility. In your scenario that is only one Visibility property in the ViewModel that all your Buttons bind to. And instead Click events, read about Commands that, in turn, change the ViewModel. All makes life easier :) Good luck.

Comment: I am just learning WPF and am interested in what you are saying, but I'm not fully understanding your comment especially regarding commands?  I am using an MVM design pattern...  In my other controls I've moved many of the control items into code after they were designed in the designer. (It's easier to use the designer interface to play with things to get them to work properly)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this on SO finally after discovering that transparent backgrounds seem to be affecting the StackPanel.  This is what fixed it for me.

[WPF Button Background Transparency on Mouse Over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953423/wpf-button-background-transparency-on-mouse-over)